# inferring shifts from lists of equipment assignments over time

Tags: java, algorithm

In my small problem, I have n users and m equipments (m and n ~ 50000). One user can use one and only one equipment at a time.

I have a list of records in this format [*u, e, t*], with *t* (time) sorted ascending. Each record mean user *u* is using equipment *e* at time *t*. The number of records is around 500 million. Assume that two nearest records with the same *u* and *e* mean that *u* is using *e* continuously. For example:

```
1, 2, 1  
3, 4, 1    
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 4 
1, 2, 5 
2, 6, 6
3, 2, 6  
3, 2, 8
```

would mean user 1 uses equipment 2 from 1 to 5.

What i want to do is from this list, infer the shift time in this format: [*u, e, st, et*] which means user *u* uses equipment *e* from start time *st* to end time *et*.

Result for the sample data would be:

```
1, 2, 0, 5  
3, 4, 0, 6  
3, 2, 6, 8
```

(assuming time starts from 0 and end at max(t), and when a pair of (u, e) is first seen, u has already started using e since the beginning of time 0. Similar for the last records.)

Given the big list (500 million record) but small enough m and n, how could I do this most efficiently?

@Edit: Possible data inconsistencies:
1: If there's only 1 record (so no end time) such as the case of [2, 6, 6] in the sample data:
--- If that's the only time user 2 and equipment 6 appear in the data set, then ignore the data point.
--- If after that record, user 2 uses another equipment, let say 7 at 10, then 2 uses 6 from 6 to 10.
--- If after that record, equipment 6 is used by another user, let say 10 at 11, then 2 uses 6 from 6 to 11.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that records come in pairs?  (i.e. start+end)

Comment: @Oli: no. in that case the shift would be counted until the next occurence of that equipment with another user, or that user with another equipment.

Comment: What do you need to do if there are inconsistent data? (no begin record, no end record, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define two structures (I know this is Java, but let's assume a generic algorithm):

```
struct user_record {
    int machine_idx;
    int start_time;
}

struct machine_record {
    int user_idx;
    int start_time;
}
```

Given that a user cannot be using more than one piece of equipment at the same time, you could create an array/vector of `user_record`s, one for each user (you said this is ~ 50k, so this should be tractable), and an array/vector of `machine_record`s, one for each machine.  Initialise all elements' `idx` members to -1 (to indicate not currently active).

Then every time you encounter an input record, check the state of the corresponding `idx` fields in the `user_record` and `machine_record` arrays.  There are three possibilities:

1. **Both are -1.**  This is a start point, so set those elements to "point" at each other, and record `start_time` in each one.
2. **Both are not -1, and consistent.**  This is an end-point, so simply create an output record, and reset those elements' `idx` fields back to -1.
3. **At least one is not -1, but they are inconsistent.**  You will need to create two output records, overwrite the elements with the new values, and also set the corresponding old machine/user indices to -1.

This is *O(N)* time (where *N* is the number of input records).

*Note: The output will be sorted by end-times.*

Comment: Thanks Oli. I think the main problem here is the inconsistent data. This is a real problem I'm solving, so I'm not sure I thought of all possible scenarios in which the data could be inconsistent. I think that's the biggest issue.

Comment: @Thi: Ok, but then you need to completely reword your question!  The algorithm design may depend entirely on how you want to handle inconsistencies.  We do not know the system constraints, nor the possible inconsistencies, nor what the output of your system needs to be in such cases, so we cannot help you figure that out...

Comment: @Thi: See updated answer, which should address your new specifications.

Comment: This is on the right track, but you're not tracking enough information to create an output record.

Comment: @btilly: Ah yes, that's an important detail (although trivial to implement).  Let me update my answer.

Comment: You still don't have enough information to create the right output records.  See my answer.

Comment: @Oli: Thanks. However, during a shift, like user 1 and equipment 2 in the updated example, a pair of user and equipment might appear many times in the input (see updated example). Are you assuming that they appear only twice?

Comment: +1: I would assume that most of your time would be spent reading the data from disk. I would estimate you will spend about 2 minutes reading the data, about 10 seconds of processing time and about 2-4 minutes writing the results. ;)

Comment: @Thi Duong Nguyen, I don't see why you would.  You only need to keep track of the start and identify the end of use. It doesn't matter how often this happens.

Comment: @Thi: No, I'm not assuming that.  Every time you hit an inconsistency, you output a record (or two), and then update your array elements.  This process is repeated for each inconsistency.

Comment: @btilly: I'm not sure what you're suggesting is missing from my answer?  (Apart from the fact that we don't actually need to store start-time in both user *and* machine records).

Comment: @Oli-Charlesworth: The stated requirements and the example are inconsistent.  The example given would have the interval be from the first to the last time that the record was seen, so when you encounter a different mapping you need to have stored two times.  However in the clarified requirements you don't resolve things that way.

Comment: @btilly: Ah yes, I see what you mean.  The example at the end of the OP's post doesn't actually make sense; if we've already decided that User 2 starts using Equipment 7 at time 10, then he cannot simultaneously be using Equipment 6 until time 11.

Comment: Thanks all for your help! I solved the problem finally, thanks to ideas from both Oli and btilly, and also from the discussion here.

Answer (score 1):

@Oli-Charlesworth is on the right track but with insufficient detail.

What you need is to have two vectors, one for user and one for machine.  The machine one points at the user.  The user one points at the machine.  One of those vectors, it doesn't matter which one so I'll make it the user, has to also track the first time they were associated, and the last time they were associated.

Initialize everything so that each user is pointing at -1 (no machine), and each machine is pointing at -1 (no user).  Here is pseudo-code for how to process your records:

```
for (user, machine, time) in records:
    # By user.machine I mean look up the machine the user currently points at
    if user.machine <> machine:
        output_record_and_clear(user)
        if machine.user <> user:
            output_record_and_clear(machine.user)
        user.machine = machine
        machine.user = user
        user.start_time = time
    user.end_time = time

def output_record_and_clear (user):
    if -1 <> user.machine and user.start_time < user.end_time:
        emit(user, user.machine, user.start_time, user.end_time)
    user.machine.user = -1
    user.machine = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by sorting the file in place by user or machine (since it's one to one, it shouldn't matter) and then by time and then the problem is easy, just go line by line and output the shift.

You could also do it in memory, line-by-line, by keeping a hash-table of machines in use and the last time they were used, when you see a machine again, output the time used and update the table.  With only 50,000 machines, this should work fine.

Comment: Might be feasible if this is a single shot operation.  While worst case 500m lg 500m isn't exactly going to be instant, it might work.

Comment: @thi-duong-nguyen: Sorting is the standard way to process large data sets.  If it doesn't work, nothing else will either.  @spinning_plate: What if user 2 uses machine 3, then 5, then 3 and nobody else uses 3 in the meantime.  If you sort by machine then process, you'll think that user was using machine 3 at the same time that user was actually on machine 5.  So your solution doesn't work.

Comment: @btilly: With the specified problem, sorting is unnecessary.

Comment: @oli-charlesworth: I am aware that sorting is not needed in this case.  But the point remains.  If sorting is too slow to consider, then you have too large a data set for your hardware.

Comment: @btilly: Yes, in general, that's a fair point.  Although an "online" algorithm (that doesn't need to store the entire data-set) opens up the ability to run on non-traditional architectures, such as GPU or FPGA.